# Static IP injection to guest VM in Win2k8

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, virtualization, powershell, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to inject IP address and do network configuration of a CentOS VM running on Windows server 2008?

In Win2k12 there is SetGuestNetworkAdapterConfiguration using which IP address can be injected, I did not come across anything similar for win2k8.

I cannot use plink to run some script on guest to set IP as plink requires IP to connect. I can neither do PS-Remoting as the VM is a linux guest.

Have not found anything on net that says "no it's not possible". So, I want to confirm if it is possible.

Comment: No, I cannot use DHCP to assign the IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the "no it's not possible" statement from Microsoft.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7ff69b62-59dd-49c1-aa3e-8435076b1cb6/static-ip-injection-to-guest-vm-in-win2k8-r2

Answer (score 0):

Cloud systems such as openstack (and Microsoft Azure) use cloud-init to provision those things. Cloud-init is fairly flexible and should allow you to for instance mount an iso into the vm with the provisioning info. I would look into that. It would require your VM templates to already be setup with cloud-init before you use them to spin VMs.

Comment: Thanks, but its not a cloud system. A physical win2k8 R2 machine which has HyperV running on it and has CentOS VM for which I need to set IP (The VM has integration services installed)

Comment: I'm not saying use a cloud system, I'm saying that there is a componen called cloud-init lots of cloud systems are using, and it would probably do what you need.